# ML.NET tensorflow half_plus_two

Tags: c#, tensorflow, real-time, inference, ml.net

I am trying to compare performance of evaluating a prebuilt tensorflow model with different inference methods.  I currently have the tensorflow serving `half_plus_two` toy model being served in an Ubuntu docker VM which produces the following results:

GRPC: ~1700 predicts per second

REST: ~800 predicts per second

My end-use application (framework 4.5 with API) is a C# environment.  I'd like to compare ML.NET's performance to tensorflow serving's REST and GRPC by using the ML.NET prediction/predictionengine within my end-use application.

#### Environment

- The model is already trained
- Inference is done by feeding a single float value to the model then processing the returned prediction
- End use application will be feeding real time data at very high rates per second
- Tensorflow 2.x to create the model and save in the `saved_model` format

#### ML.NET code

```cs
class TestProgram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            new ModelBuilder();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // investigate
        }
    }
}

public class ModelBuilder
{
    private readonly MLContext mlContext;
    private string userDesktop = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop.ToString();

    // feed these values to the pretrained tf model.
    // expected results are 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 respectively
    private float[] testData = new float[] { 0.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f, 6.0f };

    public ModelBuilder()
    {
        this.mlContext = new MLContext();
        var tfPretrainedModel = this.mlContext.Model.LoadTensorFlowModel(Path.Combine(userDesktop, @"TF\half_plus_two\1\saved_model.pb"));

        var predictionFunction = this.mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<HalfPlusTwoData, HalfPlusTwoPrediction>(tfPretrainedModel);

        HalfPlusTwoPrediction prediction = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.testData.Length; i++)
        {
            prediction = predictionFunction.Predict(new HalfPlusTwoData() { Input = this.testData[i] });

            Console.WriteLine($"Input {this.testData[i]}, Prediction {prediction.Prediction}, Expected {(this.testData[i] / 2) + 2}");
        }
    }
}

public class HalfPlusTwoData
{
    [LoadColumn(0), ColumnName("Label")]
    public float Input;
}

public class HalfPlusTwoPrediction
{
    [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
    public float Prediction { get; set; }
}
```

#### Questions

- 1 What is the proper way to use the `LoadTensorFlowModel` either to create the model or used in creating a pipeline?
- 2 Is `HalfPlusTwoData` the proper way to structure input data?
- 3 Is 'HalfPlusTwoPrediction' the proper way to structure the prediction class?

Answer (score 0):

After reading documentation, you should get a `TensorFlowModel` object from that method.

MS Docs:

```cs
TensorFlowModel tensorFlowModel = mlContext.Model.LoadTensorFlowModel(_modelPath);
```

As for your 2 classes, that is the way to do it. However, you usually have some data that gets featurised and that should be included in the first class. Similar with your prediction class, it should produce extra columns such as Score(s) and Probability. Though note that only some models will have probability like Binary Classification models.

MS Docs (Sentiment Analysis):

```cs
public class SentimentData
{
    [LoadColumn(0)]
    public string SentimentText;

    [LoadColumn(1), ColumnName("Label")]
    public bool Sentiment;
}

public class SentimentPrediction : SentimentData
{

    [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
    public bool Prediction { get; set; }

    public float Probability { get; set; }

    public float Score { get; set; }
}
```

Ignore that they have different column numbers. This is purely based on how your data is set out.

Links:

Covers input and prediction class layout: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/sentiment-analysis

Specifically about Tensorflow Models: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/text-classification-tf